# LWC That Contains Two LWCs Is Showing Neither Properly

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

According to SF, to nest an LWC inside another LWC you use:

```
<template>
    <c-lwc-component></c-lwc-component>
</template>
```

But I have two working componets nested in another like this, and neither component is displaying properly - one only displays a header with no data, and the other displays nothing at all.

```
<template>
    <c-related-list></c-related-list>
    <c-opp-track-tree></c-opp-track-tree>
</template>
```

Is there something else that the documentation isn't mentioning? There is a bunch of code of course, but they made it seem as though this was all that is needed to nest an LWC inside another.

I have target configs in one of the LWCs, does that mean it cannot be placed into another?

```
<targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="strTitle" type="String" label="Title" description="Enter the title you would like for this related list component"/>
            <property name="objectName" type="String" label="Object Name" description="Enter the API name of the child object (i.e. Guitar__c)"/>
            <property name="parentFieldAPIName" type="String" label="Parent Field API Name" description="Enter the API name of the master-detail relationship field on the child object (i.e. Contact__c)"/>
            <property name="sortfield" type="String" label="Field for Sorting" description="Enter a field API name by which to sort the records in ascending order. These data types are NOT supported: multi-select picklist, rich text, long text. Picklist sorting is defined by the picklist order specified on the field in setup."/>
            <property name="fieldName1" type="String" label="Field 1 API Name" description="Enter a field API name"/>
            <property name="fieldName2" type="String" label="Field 2 API Name" description="Enter a field API name"/>
            <property name="fieldName3" type="String" label="Field 3 API Name" description="Enter a field API name"/>
            <property name="fieldName4" type="String" label="Field 4 API Name" description="Enter a field API name"/>
            <property name="fieldName5" type="String" label="Field 5 API Name" description="Enter a field API name"/>
            <property name="fieldName6" type="String" label="Field 6 API Name" description="Enter a field API name"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
```

Thank you

Comment: If I had to take a guess I would have a look on the casing. for instance: instead of "<c-opp-Track-Tree></c-opp-Track-Tree>" try <c-opp-track-tree></c-opp-track-tree>

Comment: Thanks but casing is correct

Comment: Are you sure?  According to the doco, you cannot have capital letters when referencing another LWC. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_folder

Comment: I mean I tried both ways of capitalization, both yielded same result. The component is there but does not load the data that the child components load just fine on their own. Do parent components require something in their .js. files?

Comment: any errors in the browser console? if not, try inspect the page and look for a div with the id="auraErrorMask", sometimes it spits how any error in components

Comment: Unfortunately no, no errors and the component is in the same kind of div that the other functioning components are in. It's like everything is fine on the client side but it is not showing the data that it is supposed to be showing. Does a parent LWC need something in order for it's child LWC to load its wire data?